# how to run property in module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I need to run **y** in **x** property, but I get an error, pleases help.

**lang-js**:

```
module.exports = {
    x: () => {
        this.y("hello world");
    },

    y: (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    },
};
```

P.S. I am noob)

Comment: From this question, and your comment on Dijkstra's answer, I believe you may have a specific usecase you haven't detailed as his answer should address your problem. 

Are you looking for classes? Please update your question with further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
const _something = {
    x: () => {
        _something.y("hello world");
    },
    y: (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    },
};

module.exports = _something;
```

Comment: I would recommend checking out @TKoL's answer, as that answers and addresses the fundamental problem you're having. Whilst this is correct, this is not good practice.

Comment: In his first way, he's doing same way but I avoid using `module.exports`, choice :) and in his second way he's shown mix of function and fat arrow function, so out of 2 which is best practice according to you?

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

```
module.exports = {
    x: () => {
        module.exports.y("hello world");
    },

    y: (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    },
};
```

This also works:

```
module.exports = {
    x: function () {
        this.y("hello world");
    },

    y: (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    },
};
```

Note in the second example: it's not an arrow function. Arrow functions behave differently in regards to `this`